# Web Application Proxy and ADFS Re-Authentication on AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, adfs

I have an MVC application that is authenticated with Federation Services. All the requests are routed through a Web Application Proxy, which redirects to ADFS for authorisation if necessary, and the security tokens passed to our app.

When the session expires the WAP redirects to ADFS and an automatic reauthorisation happens. Which is fine for a normal page load.

But when a page makes an ajax call we get a 307 redirect, which our jquery ajax calls fail to handle. There is a CORS issue as the ADFS redirect is to a different domain.

I'd like to be able to intercept this call and display a message or redirect to the login page. How can I achieve this?

I have the following restrictions:

- We must use WAP
- I'm not able to change any configuration on WAP. Which means I can't add an  Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the redirect.
- As we're using WAP my app doesn't even know of any authorisation failures and I can't send back a 401 to be handled by the client side code, which is what I'd normally do

So I think I need a JQuery/JavaScript solution to this.
Thanks